# Отправка формы

Tags: jquery, javascript, checkbox, php

Как сделать на jquery, когда отмечаешь чекбокс и нажимаешь на кнопку, он вместо отправки формы переходит по ссылке? Ну и, соответственно, если чекбокс не отмечен, то отправляется форма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По примеру iksuy, но не ajax, а отправка формы. )

```
$("#your_button").click(function(){
  if($("#your_checkbox").is(':checked')){
     location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
     $('#form_id').submit();
  }
})
```

Comment: Переход по ссылке не работает, как я понял, надо сначала остановить форму?

Comment: Если это кнопка submit (<input type="submit">) то да, надо остановить отправку.

Answer (score 4):

**UPD**

```
$("#your_button").click(function(){
     if($("#your_checkbox").is(':checked')){
         location.href = url;
     } else {
         $.ajax(...)
     }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5t77dkg4/

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Обновил со ссылкой на jsfiddle.